# Implementing Pathfinding in Python Using Directed Graphs

Tags: python, search, graph, path-finding

We were given this exercise in which we are to implement pathfinding with directed graphs.

The goal is to go from start -> mid -> end with the fastest possible way.

Input starts with `Locations` and `Roads` under one string. Then follows `Roads` lines with the format `location1 location2 t`. `t` denotes the time it takes to go from `location 1` to `location 2`. All of these descriptions are **directed**. The last line contains `start mid end`. We have to start from `start`, then go to `mid`, then finally stop at `end`.

If there are no possible ways, print `impossible`. Otherwise, print the least amount of time it will take to finish.

Example:

```
3 2         (Locations Roads)
1 2 1       (Description 1)
2 3 1       (Description 2)
1 2 3       (Start Mid End)

Output: 2

3 1         (Locations Roads)
1 2 1       (Description 1)
1 2 3       (Start Mid End)

Output: impossible
```

Here's my code but this one cannot check all the possible ways and I still do not know how. It only checks if we can directly go from start, to mid, to end.

```
locations, roads = list(map(int, input().split()))
d = {}

for road in range(roads):
    l1, l2, cost = list(map(int, input().split()))
    d[l1, l2] = cost

o, a, b = list(map(int, input().split()))

isCancel = True
if len(d) < 2: print("impossible")
else:
    count = 0
    
    if d[o, a] and d[a, b]:
        count += d[o, a]
        count += d[a, b]
        isCancel = False
    else:
        print("impossible")

if not isCancel: print(count)
```

Comment: since you have to find the least amount of time, try implementing Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: Write a function that finds the shortest path between two nodes. Then call it twice, once to go from `start` to `mid`, and then again from `mid` to `end`.

Comment: @zetamoon I'll look up on that and try to implement it.

Comment: @user3386109 how would that function look like?

Comment: [It looks like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue).